# Задание шага в цикле

Tags: циклы, julia

Допустим, у меня есть цикл

```
for i in a:b
   ...
end
```

Как сделать так, чтобы с каждой итерацией `i` изменялась не на единицу, а на какое-то произвольное число?

Comment: Ответ вам уже дали, но я дополню. Если вам с каждой итерацией нужно увеличивать i на разное значение, или даже уменьшать, то это можно прописать в самом цикле. Например в условии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Синтаксис в данном случае будет таков:

```
for i in a:step:b
   ...
end
```

Например:

```
for i in 0:10:100
   println(i)
end
```